# How to get the list of active worker queue names in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, web-worker

I am running Laravel in Docker, and I have 3 workers with different name. I want to know if those queues are active and can fire a job.

I have 3 workers. `default`, `high` and `important`. I want to know if my `important` queue is running. Seems like when in `app/Console/Kernel.php` the `onQueue('important')` is not running.

Comment: can you explain in brief?

Comment: I have 3 workers. `default`, `high` and `important`. I want to know if my `important` queue is running. Seems like when in `app/Console/Kernel.php` the `onQueue('important')` is not running.